# Strange behavior on the FAQ... (hidden link?)

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I was at the superuser.stackexchange faq using the most recent stable version of Chrome on my Pentium 3POS, and I ran into some interesting behavior.

Some of the divs that are direct descendents of the `col-summary` div class turn my cursor into a link-hover cursor (the hand that gives the user the finger *hehe*).

[image: The top-most four black dots illustrate the effected area. The fifth black dot was a mistake. **WOOPS!**]

Comment: Can't reproduce, are those black dots indicating where it happens for you?

Comment: @slhck Yes, that's what they're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, G.

Comment: May I ask, is anyone else able to reproduce this on the site?  I'm inclined to believe it's some kind of glitch with Chrome.  I don't see how the site could be causing this behavior, honestly.

Comment: It's probably related to the disclosure of sections. If a section is not displayed completely, the area you indicate is clickable, and will show the additional explanation below if clicked. If you click the section header, is should hide parts of the explanation. If you click again, it should show them again. Maybe it disappears if you toggle manually, and not indirectly via anchors?

Comment: Good guess.  That doesn't seem to be the case, Daniel.  It's a fair assumption, but I don't see any expanded content.  Unless there's something else going on...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Daniel Beck comments](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3583/strange-behavior-on-the-faq-hidden-link#comment-8692),

> If a section is not displayed completely, the area you indicate is clickable, and will show the additional explanation below if clicked.

When the section is expanded like that, the cursor is then usually turned into a regular text cursor. However, this change was missing for the copy of the section that's displayed at the top of the page when you directly link to a section. This is fixed in the next build of the site. Thanks!

Comment: Okay.  Thanks, for writing.